# How can I find the max value between certain index values in an array (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array in python:

```
a = np.array([20, 21, 19, 85, 25, 31, 21, 99, 3])
```

and I want to find the max value between indices 2 and 5 to return 85. How can I do this?

I know `a.max()` will output the value 99, but I am not sure how to specify the range.

Comment: Do you know about slicing?

Comment: try `a[2:5].max()`

Answer (score 3):

Just use slicing.

```
a = np.array([20, 21, 19, 85, 25, 31, 21, 99, 3])
a[2:5].max()
```

gives 85 as max value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `a[2:5].max()`.

It will search in the sub array containing the elements you're interested in.